# Why does my training function throw up the Name error "name decaying is not defined"?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy-transformers

So, i am new to NLP, and i am trying to train a text classifier using the spacy_transformers. this code has been shown to run, but it throws up errors on my computer. As a side note, could it be caused by the fat that i am running it on a cpu?

```
def train_classifier(n_epoch:int=5, 
                     train_data:list=None, 
                     val_text:tuple=None, 
                     val_label:list=None, 
                     batch_size:int=32, 
                     lr:float=1e-3):
    train_stats = []
    dropout = decaying(0.2, 0.1, 0.3) # Gradually decrease dropout rate from 0.2 to 0.1
    # Cyclic triangular rate (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186)
    learn_rates = cyclic_triangular_rate(
        lr / 3, lr * 3, 2 * len(train_data) // batch_size
    )

    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        batches = minibatch(train_data, size=batch_size)
        losses = {}

        for batch in batches:
            optimizer.trf_lr = next(learn_rates)
            texts, cats = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(
                texts, 
                cats, 
                drop = next(dropout),
                sgd = optimizer,
                losses=losses)
```

and then when i pass the function

```
train_classifier(n_epoch=10, train_data=train_data, val_text=val_text, val_label=val_label, batch_size=32, lr=2e-6)
```

i get the following error

```
<ipython-input-55-5bb071ef310c> in train_classifier(n_epoch, train_data, val_text, val_label, batch_size, lr)
      6                      lr:float=1e-3):
      7     train_stats = []
----> 8     dropout = decaying(0.2, 0.1, 0.3) # Gradually decrease dropout rate from 0.2 to 0.1
      9     # Cyclic triangular rate (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186)
     10     learn_rates = cyclic_triangular_rate(

NameError: name 'decaying' is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? `decaying(0.2, 0.1, 0.3)` appears to be a call of a function that will need to be defined in the outer scope in order for this function to run.

Comment: This issue has been solved. I failed to import this  "from spacy.util import decaying, minibatch, compounding". Its running now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with spacy, but after a few google searches it looks like this function may be dependent on spacy's [util.decaying](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.decaying) function. Without the decaying function loaded into memory, this `train_classifier` function will throw a `NameError`. 
The code for the `decaying` function is as follows and can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/5f2afa047927675795f9cd11f4c5d2a520dd68cf/spacy/util.py#L531).

```
def decaying(start, stop, decay):
    """Yield an infinite series of linearly decaying values."""

    curr = float(start)
    while True:
        yield max(curr, stop)
        curr -= decay
```